# Describe all orthogonal unit vectors to $-5i-9j-4k$, $7i+8j+9k$, $\vec{0}$

Tags: linear-algebra

I have been trying to solve this problem:

*Describe all orthogonal unit vectors to $-5i-9j-4k$, $7i+8j+9k$, $\vec{0}$*

I have solved probles like this one, but with only two vectors... but I don't know the technique for this one.

Some suggestion, tip, ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:**

Take the cross product of $-5i-9j-4k$ and $7i+8j+9k$, and then normalize the result.

Note that the $0$ vector is orthogonal to all vectors.

Comment: What about the zero vector? Thanks.

Comment: It is orthogonal to all vectors since its inner product with any vector is $0$.